# Import contacts into Android application?

Tags: java, android, import-contacts

I am new in Android and I have a question for everyone.

Currently, I am developing an anti-theft application and I would like to have a remote lock lost phone function in my apps. But user needs to set a mobile phone number during setting so only SMS sent out from this number can trigger this function... Can I import the contacts in the phone and user choose one of the contacts to be this predefined number? Is it possible? Thanks